# Fade in entire website after loading.gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

If possible show a loading.gif in the centre then after the 5 images in the website loaded fade in the entire website contents and remove gif

So for a few seconds the website will be just black screen with loading gif image then everything fades in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this plugin for effect you want.

1. [Preloader Plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-preloader-image/)
2. http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/preloader/Demo.html